# How to retrieve images into Imageslider from firebase

Tags: android, firebase

how to get that imageUrl list into imageSlider..

It retrieve the first two images instead of all the images ?!!

Here is my Database

Slider
Slider2
imageUrl0:
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sho..."
imageUrl1:
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sho..."
imageUrl2:
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sho..."
imageUrl3:
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sho..."
imageUrl4:
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sho..."
sliderName:
"Slider2"

And here is my code ( denzcoskun library)

```
    imageSlider = findViewById(R.id.image_slider);

    final List<SlideModel> slideModels = new ArrayList<>();

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Slider")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    int k = (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()){



                            int i = 0;
                                while (i <= k) {
                                    slideModels.add(new SlideModel(data.child("imageUrl" + i).getValue().toString(),
                                            data.child("sliderName").getValue().toString(), ScaleTypes.FIT));

                                    imageSlider.setImageList(slideModels, ScaleTypes.FIT);
                                    i++;

                                }



                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

}
```

}

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Same for the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the code and JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to more easily test with your code/data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: i try to retrieve /display images from firebase database name imageUrl0, imageUrl1 and so on under one name (sliderName). but i get the images only from imageUrl0 & imageUrl1. i hope you understand !